# Not finding usernames already in the Firebase Database with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am trying to check my Firebase database to see if there is already a username taken within the database. Unfortunately, when I use a username which is already saved in there, it doesn't let me know. Code below.

```
@objc func pushedToRegister(_ sender: SignInSignUpButtons) {
    checkUserNameAlreadyExist()

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            self.errorMessage = (error?.localizedDescription)!
            print(error!)
            self.showErrorView(forReason: 0)
            return
        }
        else {
            print("Registration was successful!")
            //Here we should go back to the home screen where the message at the top should say welcome back USER!

            if let userID = user?.user.uid {

                //Create User Profile

                let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
                let usersRef = databaseRef.child("Users").child(userID)

                let usernameValue = ["username":self.username.text]

                usersRef.updateChildValues(usernameValue, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

                    if err != nil {
                        print(err!.localizedDescription)
                        self.showErrorView(forReason: 2)
                        return
                    }

                    //Profile created and updated!
                    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

                })

            }
        }
    })

}

func checkUserNameAlreadyExist() {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    var usernameTaken = false
    ref.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: username.text!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists(){
            usernameTaken = true
            print("username taken")
        }else{
            usernameTaken = false
            print("username available")
        }
    }) { error in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    if usernameTaken == false{
        //do stuff with unique username
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, every time I type in the same username, it lets me create a new profile everytime. It does not alert me to the fact that the username is already taken.

Comment: Do you see the "username available" print in the console? With your code right now, it will create the new user every time, you need to write a condition for the Auth.auth().createUser statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase functions are asynchronous, so they do not block the rest of the code from running. If you want your code to wait for a function to complete, one option is use closures. You can check out my [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/07/swift-closures-and-firebase-handling.html) on closures to see some examples.

Also, the code shown doesn't actually do anything to prevent the rest of the function from running. You need to write some sort of condition to handle that. For example, you could use a boolean in your completion handler, like this:

```
func checkUserNameAlreadyExist(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: username.text!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            usernameTaken = true
            print("username taken")
            completion(true)
        } else {
            usernameTaken = false
            print("username available")
            completion(false)
        }
    }) { error in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

Then in `pushToRegister`, you check if the boolean is true before proceeding.

```
@objc func pushedToRegister(_ sender: SignInSignUpButtons) {
    checkUserNameAlreadyExist() { isTaken in
        if (isTaken == true) {
            // show some message to the user
            return
        }
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
                print(error)
                self.showErrorView(forReason: 0)
                return
            }
            print("Registration was successful!")
            //Here we should go back to the home screen where the message at the top should say welcome back USER!
            if let userID = user?.user.uid {

                //Create User Profile
                let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
                let usersRef = databaseRef.child("Users").child(userID)
                let usernameValue = ["username":self.username.text]
                usersRef.updateChildValues(usernameValue, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                    if let err = err {
                        print(err.localizedDescription)
                        self.showErrorView(forReason: 2)
                        return
                    }

                    //Profile created and updated!                       
                    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works really well. However, this may seem like a silly question..... but how come the database refreshes every time you stop the app from running and then run it again? E.g, if I run the app, sign in with the username "Bob", then try to sign up again (with "Bob"), it says "username is taken". If I stop the app running, and then run it again I am able to sign up as "Bob" again.